# How to make back button from activity to fragment by using onOptionsItemSelected?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Below are the coding which I want to go back to the fragment page from activity page:-

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(id == android.R.id.home)
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(TuitionPackageActivity.this, FilterTuitionCentreActivity.class));
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

As shown image below, this is what happen when I click on back button, it takes time and flash like this, but it go to the fragment page that I want:-
[image]

Im using this back button as shown below image:-

[image]

Toolbar coding show below:-

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.parents_login_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("PARENTS LOGIN PAGE");
```

Comment: on back button click start/reload the activity which will host your fragment. pass a value in intent bundle which will let you identify which fragment to load.

Comment: can you please be more precise about your question?

Comment: @WajidAli Sir.. Can you please example of coding below?

Comment: @DineshNeupane I want to make back button (in the toolbar) from activity to the fragment...

Answer (score 0):

override the onBackPressed method and do what you want like below

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
     super.onBackPressed();
    //do what you want when back pressed
     startActivity(new Intent(TuitionPackageActivity.this,FilterTuitionCentreActivity.class));
}
```

You need to add custom tool bar in your xml with title text you want

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/myToolbar">

<TextView
  ....
  ..../>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Then add an action for that button in your activity

```
Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.myToolbar);
//set backbutton
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_back_button);
//set onClickListener for it
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         onBackPressed();
    }
});
```

Comment: Sir, I dont want to use back press on an Android, I want to do the back button as shown above image sir. I put the back button in my toolbar..

Comment: I already try out your updated answer, still having the same issue sir..